# Suppress warning message "This item contains attachments that are potentially unsafe" Outlook attachment outgoing mail

Tags: c++, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

I have my own outlook add-in which talks to my own server.
The add-in is developed in C++(Visual Studio 2015)
While sending a new mail having blocked attachment type(e.g. .exe, .bat) outlook gives below warning message

**This item contains attachments that are potentially unsafe. Recipients using Microsoft Outlook may not be able to open these attachments. \n do you want to send anyway?"  "Yes", "No", "Help"**

I want to suppress/disable this message programmatically.

Is there a way to do so? Any function which can suppress this message, as I want to  display my own custom messaged based on file type that is attached in mail.

Comment: Is a mail containing such files not malware today anyway? I don't think you can disable that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `MailItem.Send`, you can call `IMessage:"SubmitMessage` if Extended MAPI is an option. `IMessage` can be retrieved from `MailItem.MAPIOBJECT`.